# connect to Sqlite database using java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I need to connect to a Sqlite database, I am using following code but I reckon it connects to a database in memory. how can I connect to a database on my disk.

```
        String sDriver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
        String Database = "NyDatabase.sqlite";
        String sJdbc = "jdbc:sqlite";
        String sDbUrl = sJdbc + ":" + Database;
        Class.forName(sDriver);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sDbUrl);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        // result = st.executeQuery(Select).toString();
        rs = st.executeQuery(Select);
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                result[i] = rs.getString(i);
        }
        conn.close();

                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: This looks ok to me, why do you think it is connecting to a database in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the correct JDBC URL to specify the database file.

See [How to Specify Database Files](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC#HowtoSpecifyDatabaseFiles) in the documentation of the JDBC driver for SQLite (assuming that that's the JDBC driver you're using).

Answer (score 4):

You should have:

```
 String sDbUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/path/to/myDB.db";
```